# Where can I ask a question about setting up a WordPress blog?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I thought I was supposed to use WordPress Dev. But I got two ticks from the users there that I shouldn't ask my questions there.

Comment: I think because they specialize in plugins and theme dev instead of newbie questions like how to set a site up. haha

Answer (score 2):

From [WordPress.SE Help Center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ***Note that we do not handle questions:***
>    That require professional hands-on involvement:
>           overly complex and specific things (known as work for me for free)
>           recovering from hacks and server issues
>
> Regarding WordPress.com support issues
>           setup, feature, account, and other user support issues - try WordPress.com support
>           questions regarding the use of WordPress.com - try [WebApps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Web Applications is the place to go if your blog is hosted on WordPress.com.

If it's a self hosted blog then you should be able to ask on the WordPress.StackExchange site.